# Does User ID on Xing OAuth change when using Test Key?

Tags: oauth, python-social-auth, xing

I get a slightly changing User ID's on sign up/login when authenticating with xing oauth. Something like:
`37578662_a467ef` and `37578662_76a7fe`.
Does somebody know if the user id changes when using a xing test key? Or if I could rely on the first part (before underline) to be equal and consistent on login?

Using python-social-auth and Django

Best
Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sry, found the answer. The user-id relies to the xing-app that asks for the user, which can only be configured by one developer account...

So you need to use the same credentials to ask for the users to be able to find the same user by using the user-id again.